# logrotate create one compressed archive from log files with different file names

Tags: logs, logrotate

I have a log folder under under `/var/USER/mylogs` and there on a daily basis log files in format `"DATE-mylogile.log"`. DATE is formatted as `"%d-%m-%Y"`.

So in my folder i have for example these log files:

```
12-01-2024-mylogfile.log
13-01-2024-mylogfile.log
14.01-2024-mylogfile.log
...
```

Now i want to use logrotate to rotate the logs. My test-Configuration looks like this:

```
/var/USER/mylogs/*.log {
weekly
rotate 4
compress
missingok 
dateext 
dateformat -%d-%m-%Y
}
```

But when logrotate runs it creates and gz-Archive for every single log file like:

```
12.01-2024-mylogfile.log-12-03-2024.gz
13.01-2024-mylogfile.log-13-03-2024.gz
14.01-2024-mylogfile.log-14-03-2024.gz
```

But i want that logrotate creates weekly one gz-Archive which includes all the single log files from the week, so that there is only one gz-Archive like:

```
mylogfile.log-14-03-2024.gz
```

But there i'm stuck - so is it possible and how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit more of research i found a post [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/661567/rotate-log-files-with-timestamp-in-file-name) where the answer is given.

So it is not possible to rotate logs with time/date in the filename. logrotate is designed to use a log file which is everytime the same and the application writes on this single log file.

Answer from linked [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/661567/rotate-log-files-with-timestamp-in-file-name) post:

> "If you're already creating the files with the date in the name,
> logrotate isn't the answer; it is based around the idea of the
> application always writing to the same log file (e.g.
> /var/log/app/output.log), and then logrotate takes care of
> renaming/compressing the files and telling the app to re-open the
> original target file again."